# Removelistener of timingSprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateAll, false, 0, true);

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks

I'm using the TweenLite class (AS3) and I have a very big project. Should I removelistener of `timingSprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateAll, false, 0, true);` in the Tweenlite.as file, after my animation is complete?

Because of the size of the project, I'm afraid that ENTER_FRAME causes a memory leak for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, although you can always ask the question to Jack Doyle at greensock.com. What's your coding environment? Do you have a profiler? It would make more sense to run some tests and do some profiling before engaging in modifying TweenLite, especially since you have a big project.

Comment: You made me smile dude ;) Ok i will ask Mr Jack. I use flash cs4, codding in flashDeveloper. One question, there are hundreds of Tweenlite.to calls i make in my project, each of them do not have removelistener for updateAll function inside class, I think it's stupid :D What you think? Why probably i may skip removeListener as you say???

Comment: As a Mac user, I'm not familiar with FlashDevelop but I think FD has a profiler. If it does, I suggest you do a little profiling before worrying about memory leaks. If you can pinpoint issues with Tweenlite, then you should ask Jack ;) More seriously, note that the listener uses weakReference.

Comment: Hi. Actually it doesn't cause a problem. I've tested it, put some trace codes, and realized that updateAll doesn't not run any time i call tweenlite.to. It runs once for all animations. I think it okey now. Thank u all.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove the event listener manually. 
The last argument, `useWeakReference` is set to true so your object will get garbage collected even with the listener present.

Read more here: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html